# Using NGINX for wildcard denial

Tags: nginx, web-server, regex

I have a URL...

```
/index.php?option=com_docman&task=doc_download&gid= // many gid's
```

I want to use an NGINX location block with a wildcard to **"DENY ALL"** any urls containing "option=com_docman"

In various regex testers....

```
^(.*)(option)(.*)(com_docman)$ // Works fine for normal regex
```

However when testing in my nginx.conf file... the following does not work.

```
location ~ ^(.*)(option)(.*)(com_docman)(.*)$ {
    Deny All;
}
```

**Bonus** Is there a way to get robots.txt to address wildcard urls in the same way?

**Edit** Not sure why downvoted... anyone want to tell me what obvious thing i'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Your basic issue seems to be syntax - `Deny` is not a valid keyword.

The documentation for nginx's access module (https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_access_module.html) provides the correct syntax, which is `deny all;`.

Potentially, you could have identified the problem by running a config check:

```
$ nginx -t
nginx: [emerg] unknown directive "Deny" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:48
```

I can't speak for why your question was downvoted, but its title and actual content don't necessary match up - you are really trying to deny access to a URL endpoint based on some parameters, rather than doing wildcard denial.

Your question also had both apache and nginx tags (see https://serverfault.com/help/tagging), while it is really only about nginx.

I suspect you might also want to check https://serverfault.com/help/how-to-ask - it isn't clear how much research you had done prior to asking the question.

Answer (score 0):

`location` directive matches only the normalized URI, and that does not include query arguments.

You can use the following to block requests that have `option` argument with value `com_docman`:

```
if ($arg_option = "com_docman") {
    deny all;
}
```